# ASP.Net check if user is internal or external

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, c#-3.0, web-parts

Can you suggest me some ways on how to identify if a user is accessing my web application internally or externally?

Some methods i tried are:

- Check browser URL (http, internal - https, external)
- using Request.isSecureConnection

I just need some additional insights.

BTW, i am using a Web Part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you could do that by checking the client's IP address. There are 3 ranges that can be treated as local (or internal) networks. 
The 3 ranges are (A , B and C classes)

```
10.0.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0)  24 bits
172.16.0.0/12 (255.240.0.0) 20 bits
192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)    16 bits
```

You can use bit wise masking to check if ip is in any of those ranges, just turn ip in HEX representation

254.245.245.254 = 0xfefefefe

Comment: This is incorrect. You can set up a router to have whatever IP address pattern you like.

Comment: Above ranges are world standard, which YOU can brake if you want! On the other hand, every company respect this standard since those ranges are not "owned" by any internet service provider, nor it is possible to expose anything in those ranges since none of ISPs will do that for you. So it is 100% sure thing since whole world respect this.

Comment: Still doesn't guarantee that someone won't break them. There's no guarantee at all.